# RetrofitError Exception

Tags: android, retrofit

I have the following code...

```
public interface GithubService {
    @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
    public List<Contributor> contributors(@Path("owner") String owner, @Path("repo") String repo);
}
```

RepositoresBusinessController.class

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("https://api.github.com").build();
GithubService service = restAdapter.create(GithubService.class);
listContributors = service.contributors(username, "retrofit");
Log.d("List Contributors", listContributors+" ");
```

Contributor.class

```
public class Contributor {
    String login;
    int contributions;
}
```

And don't print in the Log and the application goes out... there is a part of Exception

```
 725-725/com.example.githubapiexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 code here`retrofit.RetrofitError
 at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
 at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
```

Someone knows why? Thanks

Comment: try this link https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-android/issues/7

Comment: I'm looking it, but what about my code implementation it's ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrofit has a mechanism for async callbacks without having to use `AsyncTask` or a service.  Change your interface to use a callback instead of a return type --

```
public interface GithubService {
    @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
    public void contributors(@Path("owner") String owner, @Path("repo") String repo,
            Callback<List<Contributor>> contributors);
}
```

The you can call it as follows -

```
service.contributors(username, project, new Callback<List<Contributor>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Contributor> contributors, Response response) {
                // got the list of contributors
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                // Code for when something went wrong 
            }
        });
```

Comment: The user and project was capture from Edit Texts and passed like parameters.
Thanks

Comment: If it is an invalid user/project combination you will get the exception.  It is not an error in your code, just a signal from retro fit that the request went bad.

Comment: and if you are passing in the project as a parameter, you aren't using it in the call.  You have "retrofit" hard coded in the example above

Comment: I think the problem are in the CallBack. I assume the framework do the AsyncTask for me, i'm checking your code.

Comment: I've tryed this example, if i execute the code it takes arround 40 seg to get the data back from the retrofit. If i use the Advance Rest Client App (Chrome extension) it returns the raw JSON data in 1000ms, What could be causing retrofit to be so slow?

Comment: I have not seen that kind of delay with retrofit, so not sure what is going on

Answer (score 1):

When I have executed your code considering the correct params passed to method `contributors(...)` here is the complete logcat

```
Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
    at $Proxy0.contributors(Native Method)
    at com.example.retrofitsample.RetrofitActivity.onCreate(RetrofitActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
    at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
    at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
    ... 17 more
```

`Retrofit library` is used for describing `REST API` using java interface (e.g GitHubService ) , annotations and internally uses `Gson` for parsing.
You need to spawn new thread using `AsyncTask` ,IntentService or whatever suits your code because network operations should not be performed on UI thread.

Check this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

> I strongly recommend not to use following lines as solution use Thread
>   class or AsyncTask or IntentService for your code

Try adding these lines in `onCreate()` method only for checking purpose as it is not a good practice

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Hope this helps!!